# ErrorDocument in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to add an ErrorDocument (page not found) to my website.
I have the errorpage.php

```
<?php
  http_response_code(404);
?>
...
<h1>page not found</h1>
```

And my .htaccess looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /$1.html [QSA,L]

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;   includeSubDomains; preload"

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/errorpage.php
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.example.com/errorpage.php
```

If I open a not existing page like: "www.example.com/xxx" I get redirected to: "www.example.com/errorpage.php" but with the status code:

```
302 found
404 not found
```

and this is bad I only need the status code "404 not found".
Why do I get two status codes and the redirect from found to not found?

Comment: Because you are using absolute URLs, for which the manual _explicitly explains_ that you will get a redirect. Use a local URL path, if you don’t want that.

Comment: Thanks that actually helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add another RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .!errorpage\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /$1.html [QSA,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /errorpage.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errorpage.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your request is non www and first redirect 302 to www and then get http404 status from errorpage.php, remove host and check. You can also move this lines to top of your .htaccess file. Maybe it help

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errorpage.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errorpage.php
```

Comment: Even if I completely empty my htaccess file it is the same problem. There is always the 302 before the 404. I tested it on localhost with xampp and on an apache (online) server.